# Convolutional Filter - Contrast Kernel

Tags: c#, image-processing

Does the kernel (matrix) for Contrast convolutional filter exist?
I've implemented low-pass filter and many more easily in C#, but even after spending days in search of kernel values for contrast filter, I came up with nothing.

This is my low-pass filter for the reference:

```
    private double[,] _kernel = new double[,] { { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
                                                { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
                                                { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
                                                { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
                                                { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, };
    public override double[,] Kernel
    {
        get { return _kernel; }
    }

    private double _scale = 25.0;
    public override double Scale
    {
        get { return _scale; }
    }


    private double _bias = 0.0;
    public override double Bias
    {
        get { return _bias; }
    }
```

I do understand that implementing a contrast filter itself is quite easy.
`*C = ((100.0 + T) / 100.0)^2*` gives me the contrast value that I use to calculate new Blue, Green, and Red value of a pixel respectively.

```
B = ( ( ( (B1 / 255.0) – 0.5) * C) + 0.5) * 255.0

G = ( ( ( (G1 / 255.0) – 0.5) * C) + 0.5) * 255.0

R = ( ( ( (R1 / 255.0) – 0.5) * C) + 0.5) * 255.0
```

My issue is that my task requires me to implement a convolutional filter for contrast.

Any ideas on what kind of kernel I could use? Whether it be 3x3 or 5x5 doesn't really matter.

Comment: I want to increase the contrast of an image using convolutional filter. My apologies for a bad explanation. I've edited the post.

Comment: The equation `B = ( ( ( (B1 / 255.0) – 0.5) * C) + 0.5) * 255.0` cannot be implemented as a convolution. But you could implement `B = ( (B1 / 255.0) * C) * 255.0 = B1 * C` as a convolution. This would be a 1x1 convolution kernel.

Comment: Does the value of my 1x1 convolution kernel then depend on the amount of contrast I want?

Comment: `C` is the value you computed. If `C=1`, then no change happens. If `C<1` then the contrast is reduced. If `C>1`, then the contrast is increased.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much! Could you post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Contrast stretching corresonds to a 1x1 kernel, plus and added constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Cris Luengo, I've solved the issue. My contrast filter looks like this:

```
    private double[,] _kernel = new double[,] { { 10 } };
    public override double[,] Kernel
    {
        get { return _kernel; }
    }

    private double _scale = 1.0;
    public override double Scale
    {
        get { return _scale; }
    }


    private double _bias = 0.0;
    public override double Bias
    {
        get { return _bias; }
    }
```

Having the kernel be 1x1 was an amazing idea!
The only thing I had to change was actually use `B = ( ( ( (B1 / 255.0) – 0.5) * C) + 0.5) * 255.0` fully in order to get the contrast.

Increasing the contrast is supposed to make the shadows darker and highlights brighter, and by using only `B = ( (B1 / 255.0) * C) * 255.0 = B1 * C`, I was making both shadows and highlights brighter. By using the aforementioned formula, I was able to darken the shadows and brighten the highlights without an issue.